# Pointing subdomain to my server

Tags: subdomain, dns-servers

My bro is using a service of a third party(say, `X`), with DNS addresses:

```
ns1.x.com
ns2.x.com
```

So, bro bought a domain name, say `abc.com`. And pointed the DNS addresses with the above ones.

Now, bro wants to create a subdomain, say `mysite.abc.com` with custom content. But this service provider `X`, doesn't offer hosting of files that we give to them for the subdomain. Instead, they said they have created a subdomain and is pointing to my server(say, with an IP: `123.99.2.123`)

So, how do I add a subdomain for `mysite.abc.com` in my server? BTW, I'm having a VPS server, with root access.

So far, I can see that adding a subdomain is possible only if the main domain is added. What changes do I have to make in my server so that, when accessing `mysite.abc.com`, files from my server would be delivered?

Sorry, I am not sure whether I confused you. Let me know if you need me to rephrase the issue or explain it with visual examples or something.

Thank you

Comment: As suspected, the question is a little confusing. Who is your DNS provider? What web server are you using (Apache, IIS, etc...)? Are you using a control panel, and if not, are you familiar with editing web server configuration files?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Was having some headache over certain things. I got it working now. cPanel was preventing me from adding an addon domain which has the DNS server names put to the third party's server. I will post the details as an answer in detail.

Answer (score 2):

For a VPS with root access, follow this guide to add a subdomain:

https://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/installation/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin#sph_configure-name-based-virtual-hosts

Here's a quick example for you.

```
<virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.abc.com
  DocumentRoot /path/to/the/site/files/of/mysite.abc.com
  ServerAdmin admin@mysite.abc.com
  ErrorLog "/logs/mysite.abc.com.error.log"
  CustomLog "/logs/mysite.abc.com.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. But I got it resolved. Will post the solution as an answer.